# Having trouble changing navbar-nav background on hoever

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

The following code works fine, except when I add background-color: black and color: white to reverse the link, it won't change the colors:

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Comment: please add your html code. Thanks!

Comment: you can use jsfiddle for your demonstration

Comment: @AleshaOleg I'll post both the jsFiddle and CodePen links as I am having trouble getting jsFiddle to work.  Not sure what I am doing wrong there, maybe CodePen has a problem, and jsFiddle is showing correctly, but not sure.  http://codepen.io/jameswlytle/pen/VvZEmO  and http://jsfiddle.net/jameswlytle/wfs7980s/  Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: @AleshaOleg It appears codepen was my issue.  jsfiddle works fine!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap default menu, try this :

```
nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px; /**as in your css/
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Do come back if you still face the issue.!

Comment: That is basically the code that I have, but still no luck.  I have tried several combinations on the CSS site, as well as changing the HTML class name from navbar to navbar-custom, thinking maybe some issue in the override was preventing it from displaying correctly, all to no avail.

Comment: Sorry @CodeRomeos forgot to address my response to you.  Thanks!

Comment: it appears that all my problems stem from CodePen.io!  Thank you for your input.  I will email CodePen and make sure they are aware of the issues.  There is also the matter of making the background transparent, which CodePen was NOT doing, but jsFiddle handles perfectly!  Guess there is something to be said for building a site on a live server rather than using some online interpreter!